# How to change pi value to 0?

Tags: python, zero, pi

I have angles for theta but for the sake of deleting rounding errors, the values for pi must change to 0. In this case, the 3rd and 4th value should change to 0. Why does this not happen? Thanks!

```
thetatab = [0.0, -0.4636476090008061, 3.141592653589793, 3.141592653589793, 0.4636476090008061, -1.5707963267948966]
for i in range(len(thetatab)):
    if np.isclose(thetatab[i], 3.14159) is True:
        thetatab[i] = 0
```

Comment: Try removing the `is True` from your code

Comment: haha that worked, thanks! But why does it not work with 'is True"?

Comment: @user12581768: The return type of `np.isclose()` is not the same as the built-in `True`, so `is` does not work.